# \DocumentMetadata in class file?

Tags: documentclass-writing, document-configuration

The documentation says that `\DocumentMetadata` "has to come first in a LaTeX document, *before* \documentclass".
Is it possible to include `\DocumentMetadata` *within* an own class files, before `\NeedsTeXFormat` and `\ProvidesClass`, or does that breaks something? With other words, are the meta information already needed for the loading mechanism of a class file?

Comment: The entire point of the line is that it's for metadata about _the document_ - why would you want to put it in a class file?

Comment: @JosephWright: I understand, that certain mechanisms (esp. tagging-related) need `\DocumentMetadata`. If so, class files that use such mechanisms could enforce the setting of proper meta data. Even if that restricts the use of the class file, the restriction would be similar as for class files that need a special engine (e.g. lua). Do I have a misconception?

Comment: No you can't. Beside others the command has a similar function as had the switch from \documentstyle to \documentclass which allowed to distinguish latex2.09 from latex2e and so to choose code pathes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. There are some technical reasons (we must ensure that the PDF management code is loaded early and in the right order, and some settings like the PDF version should be done as early as possible), also document metadata should really be set on the document level, but that is not the only reason.

For the Tagged PDF Project we have to change many things to enable tagging support. It is inevitable that this will lead to visual changes and to incompatibilities with existing packages and documents. For example footnotes, lists and display blocks have been completely reimplemented and so change if you use the testphase key. Neither hyperxmp nor pdfx do work with the PDF management and their loading is suppressed. hyperref behaves is some places (e.g. colors) differently. And so on ...

It is important that such changes are made in a way that is transparent and visible to document authors and that they actively choose if they want them or not. We therefore explicitly use a trigger command that shows that the document uses new code similar to the switch from `\documentstyle` in LaTeX2.09 to `\documentclass` in LaTeX2e.

A nice side effect is that `\DocumentMetadata` triggers discussions about the Tagged PDF project ("what is this new command doing?") which improves the visibility of the project and the general goal to improve accessibility.