pdftitle from hyperref not working as before
Consider the following MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle = {A,   B and C}}% Doesn't work as I expect
%\hypersetup{pdftitle = {A{,} B and C}}% Does    work as I expect

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}

After a recent update to my now fully up-to-date TeX Live distribution, pdftitle from hyperref no longer works as it used to; I now have to put brackets around commas in a pdftitle text in order for it to grab the text after the comma.
Is this a bug or a feature? If it is a bug, how do I fix it?

I think I've seen this before try {{...}} if you haven't already

It is a feature. If you use \DocumentMetadata XMP-Metadata are added to the PDF, and in the XMP metadata the title consist of a list of titles, e.g. to store the title in different languages. To allow to pass such a list, the code uses as usual in LaTeX a comma as a list separator, at the price that you have to hide it if it should be part of the text. The language can be given as optional argument. So e.g.
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle = {A,   [de]{B, C and D}, [fr]E}} %


\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}

will give this in the XMP-data:
   <dc:title>
    <rdf:Alt>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">A</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="de">B, C and D</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="fr">E</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Alt>
   </dc:title>


Thank you very much for the explanation, Ulrike. Now I have to change quite a lot of documents but I guess that is the price for innovation. :-)

Sorry, but yes \DocumentMetadata is documented to improve  (and so change) things ;-). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712542/2388

:-) Can I expect to be able to use the {,} approach in the long run or is there a non-zero probability that this will change again? (If it might change again, I won't edit all my documents for now.)

Well there is small but non-zero probability that we decide that the list processing is not a good idea, and that we introduce some other key to setup more titles in other languages, but hiding the comma from processing will always work and never harm.
